# Unix Find & Replace Issue

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a pretty huge `.csv` file with the date at column 3 ( Example: `11/17/2015`) and i need to replace with the date format as `2015-11-17`. I tried doing using`:%s/\<11/17/2015\>/2015-11-17`.But couldn't see the change. Any suggestions on how to do this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using `vim`:

```
:%s/11\/17\/2015/2015-11-17/g
```

You can do this also with `sed` without opening the file:

```
sed -i 's/11\/17\/2015/2015-11-17/' somefile.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to escape backslash like:

```
echo "11/17/2015" | sed 's/11\/17\/2015/2015-11-17/g'
2015-11-17
```